# XML/XSLT ALink Menu in CHM connecting params in reverse

Tags: xml, xslt, chm, helpfile

I've been trying to figure out this XSLT/XML problem for the past few days (it's code I have the pleasure of trying to fix). Using XSLT, am grabbing what's in the XML tags "see" and trying to create a "see also" (or related files) ALink menu in the Windows Help File with the tags. The $filename is a global variable, so say this is somefile.xml, the $filename would be somefile.xml.

The actual problem lies when I try to link the file together to create the ALink. ( {$filename}_SEE_ALSO gets linked to node()_SEE_ALSO}, the files *do* get linked... but reversed. So say you have Function X, you want it to show Function Y in the "See Also". Normally, you would put `<see>Function Y</see>` in Function X's file (so Function X->Function Y). In the code below, however, what it does is show Function X in Function Y (Function X<-Function Y) - so in reverse. So when you click on Function X's "See also", you get a blank popup, whilst in Function Y, it would pop up with "Function X".

These are the XML tags:

```
<function>
 <showSeeAlso>
   <see>Tag1</see>
   <see>Tag2</see>
   <see>Tag3</see>
 </showSeeAlso>
</function>
```

This is the XSLT:

```
<xsl:template match="showSeeAlso">
 <object id="seeAlso" type="application/x-oleobject" classid="clsid:adb880a6-d8ff-11cf-9377-00aa003b7a11" codebase="HHCTRL.ocx#Version=4,72,8252,0">
    <param name="Command" value="ALink, MENU"/>
    <param name="Text" value="Text:See Also"/>
    <param name="Font" value="Arial,8pt,,,underline"/>
    <param name="Flags" value="1"/>
    <param name="Item1" value=""/>
    <param name="Item2" value="{$filename}_SEE_ALSO"/>
  </object>

<xsl:apply-templates select="see"/>
</xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="see">
 <xsl:param name="name" select="."/>
  <object type="application/x-oleobject" classid="clsid:1e2a7bd0-dab9-11d0-b93a-00c04fc99f9e">
  <param name="ALink Name" value="{concat(node(),'_SEE_ALSO')}"/>
 </object>

</xsl:template>
```

Any/all help greatly appreciated, this has been the bane of my existence the past few days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is going to help anyone else, but I semi-figured out a solution. I switched from ALinks to Related Topics, and fixed up the code. Here's the result:

The XML:

```
<showSeeAlso/>
<see>tag1</see> 
<see>tag2</see>
<see>tag3</see>
```

The XSLT:

```
  <xsl:if test="showSeeAlso">
    <object id="hhctrl" type="application/x-oleobject" classid="clsid:adb880a6-d8ff-11cf-9377-00aa003b7a11" codebase="hhctrl.ocx#Version=6,1,7600,16385">
    <param name="Command" value="Related Topics, DIALOG"/>
    <param name="Text" value="Text:See Also"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="see"/>
   </object>
  </xsl:if>

  <xsl:template match="see">
    <xsl:variable name="tag" select="."/>
     <xsl:variable name="count">
  <xsl:number/>
 </xsl:variable>

 <param name="Item{$count}" value="{$tag};{$tag}.html"/>

 </xsl:template>
```